# Vaadin flow Grid items duplicate rows

Tags: java, vaadin, vaadin-flow, vaadin-grid

Vaadinversion: 14.4.1

spring-boot-starter-parent: 2.2.10RELEASE

I have two items in my grid. These two items looks like:

```
Kontakt{id=11657f9e-c4f4-414f-aab2-618252db9b06'vorname='test1'...
Kontakt{id=8da74f38-2072-4fb0-8c74-aede661f02b5'vorname='test'...
```

But the grid only displays only one items and so oft like the `"itemslist.size()"`
Also they react as "one row". So I can like on the first and both get selected.

These are my `@Entity(s)`

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "std_kunde")
@Data
public class Kunde extends Kontakt {

    public Kunde() {
        super();
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return super.toString();
    }
}

@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS)
@Data
public abstract class Kontakt extends BasicEntity {

    private String vorname;
    private String name;
    ...

   
    public Kontakt() {
        super();
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Kontakt{" +
                "id=" + getId() + '\'' +
                "vorname='" + vorname + '\'' +
               ...
                '}';
    }
}


@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS)
@Data
public abstract class BasicEntity {

    @Id
    @GenericGenerator(name = "id_generator", strategy = "....KeyGenerator")
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "id_generator")
    @Column(length = 128)
    private String id;

    @CreationTimestamp
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @Column(name = "create_date")
    private Date createDate;

    @UpdateTimestamp
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @Column(name = "modify_date")
    private Date modifyDate;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "basicEntity")
    private List<Anhang> anhangList;
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "basicEntity")
    private List<Notiz> notizList;


    public BasicEntity() {
        anhangList = new ArrayList<>();
        notizList = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(id);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o){
        if(null == o)
            return false;
        if(!(o instanceof BasicEntity))
            return false;
        BasicEntity b = (BasicEntity) o;
        return b.getId().equals(this.getId());
    }
}
```

And also the Grid code

```
 @Autowired
private KundeService kundeService;

private Grid<Kunde> g;

public Dashboard() {
    g = new Grid<>(Kunde.class);
    g.addColumn(Kunde::getVorname).setHeader("Vorname");
    g.setSizeFull();
    setSizeFull();
    add(g);
}
```

I tested to build a Grid based upon an other entiy and it worked like it should. Its like the first time I have this behaivor but I dont know how actually to debug it...

EDIT 29.10.2020 ---------------------------------------------------------------

This is the `@Entity` (Notiz) which works like expected.

UI-Code

```
private Grid<Kunde> g;
    private Grid<Notiz> n;

    public Dashboard() {
        g = new Grid<>(Kunde.class);
        g.addColumn(Kunde::getId).setHeader("ID");
        g.addColumn(Kunde::getVorname).setHeader("Vorname");
        g.setSizeFull();

        n = new Grid<>(Notiz.class);
        n.addColumn(Notiz::getId).setHeader("ID");
        n.addColumn(Notiz::getTitel).setHeader("Titel");
        n.setSizeFull();
        setSizeFull();
        add(g,n);
    }

    @PostConstruct
    private void loadValues(){
        g.setItems(kundeService.findAll());
        n.setItems(notizService.findAll());
    }



@Entity
@Table(name = "ld_notiz")
@Data
public class Notiz extends BasicEntitySystemFeatures {


    private String titel;
    @Column(length = 5000)  //TODO
    private String content;
    private boolean abgeschlossen = false;

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private NOTIZ_TYP notizTyp;

    public enum NOTIZ_TYP {
        NOTIZ,
        ERINNERUNG
    }

    @ManyToOne
    private BasicEntity basicEntity;

    public Notiz() {
        super();
    }
}

@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS)
@Data
public abstract class BasicEntitySystemFeatures {
    @Id
    @GenericGenerator(name = "id_generator", strategy = "...KeyGenerator")
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "id_generator")
    @Column(length = 128)
    private String id;

    @CreationTimestamp
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @Column(name = "create_date")
    private Date createDate;

    @UpdateTimestamp
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @Column(name = "modify_date")
    private Date modifyDate;

    public BasicEntitySystemFeatures() {
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(id);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o){
        if(null == o)
            return false;
        if(!(o instanceof BasicEntitySystemFeatures))
            return false;
        BasicEntitySystemFeatures b = (BasicEntitySystemFeatures) o;
        return b.getId().equals(this.getId());
    }
```

[image: Comparing the UI Result of both Entities]

[image: Screenshot of Vaadin UI Grid not clicked row]
[image: Screenshot of Vaadin UI Grid clicked row]

Comment: One prime suspect around those things is borked equality/hashcode.  have you tried without overriding those (so back to object identity)? are you sure your IDs are not just null due to some mapping problems from the db etc (that would make those two equal too)

Comment: @cfrick Thank you for the thoughts. I add the entity where it workes like it should. I also tried to delete my custom `equals/has` Methodes and two use defaults, but its quite the same result

Comment: I also think that equals/hashCode could be the problem. @Data also generates these. Can you try without Lombok and any equals/hashCode methods

Comment: @SimonMartinelli Okay. Its was the problem with equals/hasCode. I mean its confusing why the `Notiz` works but `Kunde` not. The difference is the level of inheritance...

Answer (score 0):

a Vaadin Grid<> refers to their rows by ID. Internally, the keymapper of the grid will try to assign an ID to each row. Since any collection used to populate the Grid<> through the grid's `.setItems()`-method is internally parsed to a Set<>, Vaadin will try to use your equals-method.

If you don't have an equals-method, Vaadin employs several fallbacks, one of which is looking if your objects contain a field named `id`

A great explanation and other possible solutions for this, can be found on Github by Martin's [article on grid-and-broken-equals](https://mvysny.github.io/grid-and-broken-equals/)